# How to get Adoptable SD card encryption key with root access?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow, encryption, adoptable-storage

When I use adoptable storage on my device, then my SD card will be encrypted. Is there a way to get the  "encryption key" with root access? So if my phone dies, I can still retrieve my data from the SD card by using the key?

Related: [How does Marshmallow encryption work technically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127076/95577)

I am running Cyanogenmod 13, rooted.

Comment: Have you read this: http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html?

Comment: @Firelord No, I did not. Thanks. I now can safely encrypt it, and still be able to retrieve the data, in case something happens..

Comment: Our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) might lead you to the answer. It links to [How Android 6.0 format as internal storage feature works?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/137855/16575), where [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137857/16575) contains the details you're after at its very end :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some interesting pointer found in [Decrypting Android M adopted storage](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html) (emphasis mine):

> Android M allows for adoptable storage, which is implemented similarly to internal storage FDE -- using dm-crypt with a per-volume, static 128-bit AES key, stored in `/data/misc/vold/`. ***Once the key is extracted from the device, adopted storage can be mounted and read/written on any Linux machine.*** Adoptable storage encryption is done purely in software (at least in the current preview build), so its performance is likely comparable to encrypted internal storage on devices that don't support hardware-accelerated FDE.

Also take a look at [Corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/135803/16575), which gives a quite detailed tutorial on how to do it :)

Comment: I see the file in ES Explorer. Its size is 16 Byte. How can I extract the key from it? Assume I am not a Linux user. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi assuming you're not a Linux user, I cannot help you. See the emphasized part of my answer: the proposed solution only works with Linux. Apart from that, the file content is the key, as far as I understood.

Comment: I installed Linux on a computer just for that. I meant I am not experienced. I can see the file on ES Explorer which states its size is 16 Byte. Now, how can I extract the key from the file in my Android? All say HEX editor. Which HEX Editor can ask for root access to access that file? Is the size of 16 Byte correct?

Comment: @Royi Have you seen the [linked guide](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135803/16575)? Take a closer look at the first comment there, which should answer your question. I don't use adoptable storage myself (and don't plan to), so I cannot test and verify. And yes, 16 byte is correct – according to the [linked answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/135836/16575).