# How to encrypt full device on Android Nougat?

Tags: encryption, 7.0-nougat

I have an LG V20 but I can't find the setting for full device encryption. There is a setting to encrypt the SD card. However, I'd like to also encrypt any memory on the phone itself.

Is this possible in Nougat?

Comment: Nougat doesn't offer that feature anymore. It offers direct boot which is  [covered here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/160016/131553)

Comment: The encryption was never "full" - only user data and cache partition. The system itself was never encrypted.

Answer (score 5):

Head to Settings > Security > Screen Lock and tap your current screen lock. If “require PIN to start device” is an option, you’re running full-disk encryption.

If you’d like to convert to file-based encryption, you can do so by enabling Developer Options, then heading into Developer Options and tapping the “Covert to file encryption” option. Keep in mind that this will erase all of your data, effectively factory resetting the device!

[Here is the full tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/269422/how-to-enable-android-nougats-direct-boot-for-less-annoying-encryption/) from howToGeek.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: There's more information about Nougat's encryption in the security section of [this Ars Technica article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/08/android-7-0-nougat-review-do-more-on-your-gigantic-smartphone/10/#security).