# Decrypt /data without formatting

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

As the title suggests, is it possible on Android N (7.0/7.1)?

I Googled around but all solution suggests that I format `/data`. And if I keep using the stock ROM without flashing Forced Encryption Disabler it'll be encrypted again. So I wonder if it's possible to manually decrypt `/data`.

I'm using OnePlus 5, whose stock system is very similar to AOSP.

Author's note: [Plagiarism](https://www.questarter.com/q/decrypt-data-without-formatting-12_180777.html) is allowed as long as you're shameless.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It would help if you post you device, rom, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Stock ROM 4 1+ 5 is OxygenOS.

No, u cannot decrypt, but can only remove with format - not wipe.

Currently, working with 1+ 5; though I haven't seen similarity with AOSP, default is FBE.

U can [modify fstab.qcom with encryptable flag](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187074/245102), hence no forced FDE or FBE.