# No "Encrypt Phone" option on Android 7.0 Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: settings, security, 7.0-nougat, encryption, samsung-galaxy-s7

In order to sell my Samsung Galaxy S7, I want to clear it of all personal data. I did a full factory reset thinking this would do the trick. But, after the full factory rest, I read this [online](https://www.cnet.com/news/android-phone-wiping-fails-to-delete-personal-data/)

> ...a security firm has determined returning Android devices to factory
>   settings doesn't actually wipe them clean. Security firm Avast
>   purchased twenty used Android phones on eBay. Through extraction
>   methods, they were able to recover old emails, texts, and even photos.

I then go on to read that a full file based encryption of the phone should make it safe for resale. I plan to fully encrypt the phone with file based encryption and then do another factory reset. However, I cannot find where to encrypt the phone!

I have tried every step-by-step guide I can find online and I simply do not see the "encrypt phone" option.

I've tried from [here](https://www.androidexplained.com/galaxy-s7-enable-encryption/)

> 1. Launch the Settings Application
> 2. Scroll Down and Tap on the ‘Lock Screen and Security’ Option
> 3. Then Tap on the ‘Protect Encrypted Data’ Option

But there's no "Protect Encrypted Data" option!

I tried the answer from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161317/how-to-encrypt-full-device-on-android-nougat) StackExchange question. I went into developer options and there was no “Covert to file encryption” option anywhere on the phone!

In fact, when I search "encrypt" in settings the only thing that comes up is "Encrypt SD Card" (even when developer settings are on).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Samsung non standard implementation, OP couldn't *factory-reset and encrypt* before selling. They couldn't :

- Check if the device was encrypted
- Locate the option for encryption

Steps advised :

- Install minimal adb on your laptop
  ([Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/131553)) and check device encryption status ([Is there a way for a user to tell if their Android device is encrypted or not?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96125/131553)). Alternatively, install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) on your device and type `getprop ro.crypto.state`
- Encrypt device from Settings → Lock Screen and security → secure start up → require password ([Source](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/androidexplained/galaxy_s7_enable_encryption_protection))
- [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) after signing out from Google account, else you will have problems with factory reset protection and buyer will not be able to use your device
- Confirm device is encrypted. Decrypt device (to remove lock screen PIN ) and sell :)