# Does Samsung J7 max use full disk encryption by default?

Tags: samsung, encryption

I have just bought a new [Samsung J7 Max](http://www.samsung.com/in/microsite/galaxy-j7-max/) with Android Nougat. I have protected it using a fingerprint and passcode, but does it use any sort of encryption by default ? Either full disk or file based ? Because there is no option to encrypt or decrypt other than the sd card.

Comment: It uses file description as explained here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160016/what-is-direct-boot-or-file-encryption-in-android-n/160017#160017

Comment: @beeshyams you mean "file encryption"  ?

Comment: Yes it is file encryption