# Full Disk Encryption on Google Pixel XL vs Google Nexus 6P

Tags: nexus-6p, disk-encryption, google-pixel, 7.1-nougat

I am wondering if I have the same full disk encryption with a Google Pixel XL as I did with the Google Nexus 6P.  On the Google Nexus 6P it would not load anything before being prompted for a password, On the Google Pixel XL it appears to load into the OS before I unlock it.

1. Is it loading into the OS ( I see my wallpaper when I input the password, this suggests to me it is )?  If so, wouldn't this be less secure than with the Google Nexus 6P?
2. Can I configure my Google Pixel XL to act this way?

I know the Google Pixel XL has two disks (partitions ?) so it can update in the background and update much faster.

Comment: Firstly, on this site single Q and A's are the format . Q1 is [duplicate of this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/159721/131553).Q2- if Google designed this as a specific feature that is fundamental to core OS, I don't think it is possible

Comment: I have asked your tag question on your behalf on [Meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/is-the-tag-7-1-nougat-necessary) - let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pixels use file encryption instead of full disk encryption. Only FDE requires preboot authentication. File based will decrypt based on hardware secrets to boot the OS and background services. Once you enter you pin/code/etc, it unlocks your user based files.

Answer (score 1):

No, but, you can do so by changing encryption mode from "developer options" - convert to file encryption.