# Sony F5121: Forgot Device Encryption Passwort, locked bootloader

Tags: encryption, bootloader, locked-out, disk-encryption

I forget the device encryption password for my F5121 (locked bootloader). Is there any way to hard-reset the device, so I can use it again (I don't care about the data on it)?

I already tried some combination with Power Button + Volumne Up/Down, but I don't see any options popping up.

Also, unlocking the bootloader does not seem to work (probably I should have enabled oem unlocking in the android settings before), it says:

```
FAILED (remote: 'Command not allowed')
```

Same error, when trying to flash TWRP.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Talkback by-pass of FRP i can not post the steps and i am not the author of this, so please find a tutorial here
https://www.techeligible.com/2018/03/10/bypass-google-account-sony-xperia-android-8-0/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, please note that I cannot even start/boot android. I am locked at a boot password (encryption)

Comment: please add a picture of this

Comment: Good idea, I updated the question :-)

Comment: as i can see you use the full disk encryption, so android can not boot without password. which android version you have? if it is Marshmallow it should be possible to hard reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe it. Entering anything (but the password) for 30 times resets the phones.
I also stumbled upon this (later on), it looks like there is default password in AOSP based ROMS: [How does Marshmallow encryption work technically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127076/how-does-marshmallow-encryption-work-technically)

Comment: Good  another way is perform a  software repair using Xperia Companion. if FRP is activated you can pass it with your google account